# How to get number of items (length) from a Stata macro?

Tags: stata, stata-macros

Say I have a global macro `x`, how do I extract the number of items (space-separated unquoted words) in it?

```
global x abc xyz foo
```

I am sure it is an easy task, but I've looked in `help macro` and haven't find anything so far.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, it was right there in the manual. The macro function `word count` would do the job.

```
. global x abc xyz foo
. local len_x : word count $x
. di `len_x'
3
```

Alternatively,

```
. di wordcount("$x")
3
```

Note the need to quote the global macro in this case.